# 2D array indexing error in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm playing with 2D arrays to make a random sequence generator. I'm trying to generate 10 lists of 6 integers each, without replacement, inside a 2D array. The integers allowed are between 0 and 100. However, I keep getting list index out of range errors, and can't work out why. Here's my code:

```
import random

numbers = [i for i in range(100)]
picked = []
unpicked = []

lines = [[0 for x in range(6)] for j in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(6):
        unpicked = [x for x in numbers+picked if x not in picked]
        lines[i][j] = unpicked[random.randint(0,99)]
        picked.append(lines[i][j])
```

Comment: When `picked` grows its size, `unpicked` will get smaller and you use `randint(0, 99)` which might generate numbers that is bigger than `unpicked`'s size. Thus, an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should shrink the size that `random.randint` can choose from. Based on your application, I think it should be

```
random.randint(0, len(unpicked)-1)
```

Another thing is that in the following line

```
unpicked = [x for x in numbers+picked if x not in picked]
```

you don't need `numbers+picked`. Just put `numbers` would be enough because `numbers` always have from 0 to 99.

Comment: I've changed my unpicked to `unpicked = [x for x in lines[i]+picked if x not in picked]` as I want to generate sequences without replacement. Also, `random.randint(0, len(unpicked)-1)` gives me an `empty range for randrange()` error

Comment: Your `unpacked` should be `unpicked = [x for x in numbers if x not in picked]` `unpicked` means what is in `numbers` but not in `picked`. Thus, it should be this way. I think now the second error will be resolved.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```
import random

numbers = [i for i in range(100)]
picked = []
unpicked = []

lines = [[0 for x in range(7)] for j in range(11)]

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(6):
        #unpicked = [x for x in numbers+picked if x not in picked]
        x = random.randint(0,99)
        while(x in picked):
          x = random.randint(0,99)
        lines[i][j] = x
        picked.append(lines[i][j])
```

your logic of picking number is getting out of index.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, this works well but I need the 'unpicked' list as I need to do this without replacement.

Comment: What do you mean by replacement ? In the above example also you are not replacing anything ...

Comment: Also the above example is saving you space, which u did by creating a new array numbers

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way:

```
numbers = range(101)  # 0 ~ 100 (include 100)
random.shuffle(numbers)  # in place
pickup_num = 60
n = 6
picked = numbers[:pickup_num]
lines = [picked[i:i+n] for i in range(0, pickup_num, n)]
```